# Is there a way to calculate Renormalization Flow numerically?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, computational-physics

I have an interesting system, which possess a phase transition. I would like to apply renormalization group method on this system to find the RG flow, and critical exponent. The system is governed by two parameters, like H and T in physical systems. However, the "objective function" (like Hamiltonian in physical system) of this system is very hard to calculate. For given parameters, it can only be calculated numerically. In this situation, is it possible to numerically draw the RG flow and find the fixed point?
Thanks.

Comment: Monte Carlo has been adapted for this purpose.